# Shopify Liquid - Does lots of logic SLOW DOWN page load?

Tags: shopify, liquid

- If I have 30-40 if-statements and other Liquid logic on a page to check different things about the product for example... will that slow down page load? (Or will this be an issue only after hundreds or thousands of if-statements only?)
- Do Shopify template files even render when a visitor opens a web page in real time, or do they actually render as static files in advance, once I click "save" on a product or theme settings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shopify sites do render on page load however there is some caching too.

If you add:

`{{ 'now' | date: '%s' }}`

you will be able to see the time change on a per second basis. Although this is cool it isn't very reliable for time based functions because of the caching.

Having 30 - 40 if statements may cause some performance issues, but Shopify is running on pretty speedy AWS servers so I rarely notice any speed drops from overly complex pages. I have created large files of `if` statements that include different files on certain conditions and haven't noticed any problems.

Try checking out the network tab and seeing how long it takes to return a response from the first request.

If you are experiencing performance issues try replacing the if statements with a `{% case %}` statement instead and make use of `{% continue %}` and `{% break %}` in for loops.